# iOS Disable Page Scrolling with overflow-scrolling: touch

Tags: javascript, ios, css, scroll, dom-events

Let's say we want to make a webapp feel like a native app with "Add to Home Screen."  One of the first steps is to disable the default scrolling.  Easy, right?

```
// window or document
window.addEventListener("touchmove", function(event) {
    // no more scrolling
    event.preventDefault();
}, false);
```

That's all fine and dandy until you add `overflow-scrolling` to the mix.  To be precise, on iOS it would be `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch`.

```
/* #scrollable happens to be a ul */
#scrollable {
    overflow-y: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

By adding event prevention, hardware-accelerated scrolling in a container does not function, clearly not the intended effect.

The obvious solution looks something like this:

```
// you could do this for multiple elements, of course
var scrollable = document.querySelector("#scrollable");
scrollable.addEventListener("touchmove", function(event) {
    // no more bubbling :)
    event.stopPropagation();
}, false);
```

This solution introduces a problem, however, if you try to scroll left or right in `#scrollable`, it reverts back to the default scroll listener.  Clearly, then, you should monitor the events to see if the `touchmove` event is tracking left or right, right?  Unfortunately, no, as it will also, under circumstances I don't entirely understand, revert to the default scroll listener when scrolling vertically in the container.

Now what?  To make matters worse, we would ideally be able to handle `click` or click-like events on the individual `li`s (read: `touchstart`):

```
var items = scrollable.querySelectorAll("#scrollable li");
for (var item = 0; item < items.length; item++) {
    items[item].addEventListener("touchstart", function() {
        // handle the touch start
    }, false);
}
```

To fix this problem, we could turn to simply using `click` events, but that defaults the goal of making the webapp "feel" native due to the delay between tapping and response.  To solve this, we'll add an event listener for `touchstart` and `touchend`:

```
var items = scrollable.querySelectorAll("#scrollable li");
var activeItem = null, startTouch = null;
for (var item = 0; item < items.length; item++) {
    items[item].addEventListener("touchstart", function(event) {
        startTouch = event.touches[0];
        activeItem = this;
    }, false);
    items[item].addEventListener("touchend", function(event) {
        var touch = event.changedTouches[0];
        var deltaX = touch.pageX - startTouch.pageX
        var deltaY = touch.pageY - startTouch.pageY;
        // require the touchstart to be within 10 pixels of the touchend
        if (deltaX * deltaX + deltaY * deltaY <= 100)
            // handle "click" event
    }, false);
}
```

That's all fine and good, but we still haven't solved the problem with default page scrolling taking control of some `touchmove` events.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try swapping around the logic in your `window` and `scrollable` element listeners like so:

```
// window or document
window.addEventListener("touchmove", function(event) {
  if (!event.target.classList.contains('scrollable')) {
    // no more scrolling
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}, false);

// No special listeners needed on .scrollable elements
```

This way, you only prevent default when trying to scroll non-scrollable elements.

You will still have a problem that at the top/bottom of the scrollable content starting a drag can cause the whole app to "bounce".  To fix this problem, see [Joe Lambert's ScrollFix](https://github.com/joelambert/ScrollFix).